# Copy data from Hypersonic to Sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, liferay

I created a website using liferay with some sample pages. Later we wanted to import some 23000 users into liferay. The data is in csv format.

I dont know java. tried to insert data using C#.net and liferay webservices. No luck. So i changed the settings to point to Sql Server.

Now all the data I created for the sample site is residing in the Hypersonic DB.

Is there any way to copy the data to sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to gather all your table data from HSQLDB into .CSV format.

If you can use your original .csv file, that's great. If needed, you'll need to find a way to get your data from HSQLDB into a text file. You may have a tool already that you know of. Perhaps you could use [RazorSQL's Export Tool](http://www.razorsql.com/screen_shots.html). ([screenshot](http://www.razorsql.com/images/windows/export.gif)).

Then you can [import .csv to SQL Server using the SQL Server Management Studio Import Wizard](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/title-12). The screenshots are a bit out of date, but you'll have no trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Thank you so much Campbell. I installed RazorSQL and created csv file and imported to sql server successfully. You made my day!!!

Comment: @Vivek; my pleasure; glad to have helped!